# Creating a Color scheme GUI with Java

Tags: java, user-interface, colors

my name is Abel and I am new to java. I am trying to create a program that will allow me to enter int values into Jtextfields and use them to change the color of the bottom row of my panel. I tried turning the values in the jtextfield into ints. the IDE says that i have no obvious errors but i still cannot get the row to change colors. I want figure this out before i finish the program.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel  jp, jp1, jp2, jp3, jp4, jp5;
    JTextField jtf1, jtf2, jtf3, jtf4, jtf5, jtf6;
    JButton jbrplus, jbrneg, jbgplus, jbgneg, jbbplus, jbbneg;
    int value, value1, value2;
    String text, text1, text2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App1 KF = new App1();

    }

    App1() {
        this.setTitle("Application 1");
        this.setSize(800, 600);

        jp = new JPanel();
        this.add(jp);
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp.add(jp1);
        jp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp2);
        jtf1 = new JTextField("RED");
        jtf1.setEditable(false);
        jp2.add(jtf1);
        jbrplus = new JButton("+");
        jp2.add(jbrplus);
        jtf2 = new JTextField("    0    ");
        jtf2.setEditable(true);
        jp2.add(jtf2);
        jbrneg = new JButton("-");
        jp2.add(jbrneg);
        jp2.setBackground(Color.RED);

        jp3 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp3);
        jtf3 = new JTextField("Green");
        jtf3.setEditable(false);
        jp3.add(jtf3);
        jbgplus = new JButton("+");
        jp3.add(jbgplus);
        jtf4 = new JTextField("    0    ");
        jtf4.setEditable(true);
        jp3.add(jtf4);
        jbgneg = new JButton("-");
        jp3.add(jbgneg);
        jp3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        jp4 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp4);
        jtf5 = new JTextField("Blue");
        jtf5.setEditable(false);
        jp4.add(jtf5);
        jbbplus = new JButton("+");
        jp4.add(jbbplus);
        jtf6 = new JTextField("    0    ");
        jtf6.setEditable(true);
        jp4.add(jtf6);
        jbbneg = new JButton("-");
        jp4.add(jbbneg);
        jp4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        jp5 = new JPanel();
        jp.add(jp5);
        jp5.setBackground(new Color(value, value1 , value2));
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == jtf2 && e.getSource() == jtf4 && e.getSource() == jtf6) {
                    text = jtf2.getText();
                    text1 = jtf4.getText();
                    text2 = jtf6.getText();
                    value = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    value1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
                    value2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);
                    jp5.setBackground(new Color(value, value1, value2));
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: where do you register the ActionListener to each of the GUI button? Or how should they communicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `actionPerformed()`, you check `e.getSource()` against `jtf2`, `jtf4`, and `jtf6`, and perform the operation **only if the source is equal to all of the values simultaneously**.

You probably want “if the source is the first text field **OR** the source is the second **OR** the source is the third.

---

While `App1` implements `ActionListener`, no where are you calling `xxx.addActionListener(app1)`.  You will need to wire the `jtf2`, `jtf4` and `jtf6` to send action events to the application instance.  When you’ve done that, since they are the only things that are wired to that `ActionListener`, you don’t really need to check which one generated the event, because you would respond to any source.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add the xxx.addActionListener(). That helped to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you are missing here are:
1) Action Listener needs to be bind with '+' or '-' button(this mapping is missing).

2) Condition if `(e.getSource() == jtf2 && e.getSource() == jtf4 && e.getSource() == jtf6)` needs modification, here replace && with ||

This code should work for you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel jp, jp1, jp2, jp3, jp4, jp5;
    JTextField jtf1, jtf2, jtf3, jtf4, jtf5, jtf6;
    JButton jbrplus, jbrneg, jbgplus, jbgneg, jbbplus, jbbneg;
    int value, value1, value2;
    String text, text1, text2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App1 KF = new App1();

    }

    App1() {
        this.setTitle("Application 1");
        this.setSize(800, 600);

        jp = new JPanel();
        this.add(jp);
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp.add(jp1);
        jp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp2);
        jtf1 = new JTextField("RED");
        jtf1.setEditable(false);
        jp2.add(jtf1);
        jbrplus = new JButton("+");
        jbrplus.addActionListener(this); // Add actionListener Step#1
        jp2.add(jbrplus);
        jtf2 = new JTextField("0");
        jtf2.setEditable(true);

        jp2.add(jtf2);
        jbrneg = new JButton("-");
        jbrneg.addActionListener(this);
        jp2.add(jbrneg);
        jp2.setBackground(Color.RED);

        jp3 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp3);
        jtf3 = new JTextField("Green");
        jtf3.setEditable(false);
        jp3.add(jtf3);
        jbgplus = new JButton("+");
        jbgplus.addActionListener(this);
        jp3.add(jbgplus);
        jtf4 = new JTextField("0");
        jtf4.setEditable(true);
        jp3.add(jtf4);
        jbgneg = new JButton("-");
        jbgneg.addActionListener(this);
        jp3.add(jbgneg);
        jp3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        jp4 = new JPanel();
        jp1.add(jp4);
        jtf5 = new JTextField("Blue");
        jtf5.setEditable(false);
        jp4.add(jtf5);
        jbbplus = new JButton("+");
        jbbplus.addActionListener(this);
        jp4.add(jbbplus);
        jtf6 = new JTextField("0");
        jtf6.setEditable(true);
        jp4.add(jtf6);
        jbbneg = new JButton("-");
        jbbneg.addActionListener(this);
        jp4.add(jbbneg);
        jp4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        jp5 = new JPanel();
        jp.add(jp5);
        jp5.setBackground(new Color(value, value1, value2));
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == jbrplus || e.getSource() == jbrneg || e.getSource() == jbgplus || 
                e.getSource() == jbgneg || e.getSource() == jbbplus || e.getSource() == jbbneg) {// Condition modification Step#2           
            text = jtf2.getText();
            text1 = jtf4.getText();
            text2 = jtf6.getText();
            value = Integer.parseInt(text);
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
            value2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);
            jp5.setBackground(new Color(value, value1, value2));
        }
    }
}
```